# Returning false from click handler doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, cross-browser

In the example below, `return false` does not seem to prevent the default action after the link is clicked (because the page scrolls to the top) in Firefox 3.6 or Chrome 10 but works in Internet Explorer.

Using `event.preventDefault()` does what I need, but I'm wondering why `return false` does not work with the others.

**Side note:** I do not need to support Internet Explorer.

```
<script>
  addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function(){
      alert("Clicked!");
      return false;
    }, false);
    alert("Click handler bound!");
  }, false);
</script>

<div style="margin-top: 1200px;">
  <a id="link" href="#">Click me!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome either (http://jsfiddle.net/sj65N/).

Comment: Now it follows from the answer that it works nowhere

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`return false` works cross browser, but **only** for event handlers assigned the "DOM0" way, such as

```
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function() {
    alert("Clicked!");
    return false;
};
```

For event handlers assigned the DOM Level 2 way via `addEventListener()`, you have to use `preventDefault()`:

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    alert("Clicked!");
    evt.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

For event listeners attached via `attachEvent()` in IE, either `return false` or `window.event.returnValue = false` will do:

```
document.getElementById("link").attachEvent("onclick", function() {
    alert("Clicked!");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So, if you use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`, you have to mess with `preventDefault()` and `returnValue`?

Comment: @Eugene: No, `return false` is fine for `attachEvent()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK, this seems to be the real answer.  Thank you very much

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You say "`preventDefault()` helps" but you say it doesn't work? I'm not sure I understand. Have you tried this:

```
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        alert("Clicked!");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }, false);
    alert("Click handler bound!");
}, false);
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  This version works.  I was trying to say that just `return false` doesn't work, but using `preventDefault()` instead helps.  I don't want to use `preventDefault()` because `return false` is shorter and crossbrowser.

Comment: @Eugene: Ah, I see. If `return false` isn't working for other browsers, then it isn't crossbrowser. I'm pretty sure `return false` is for IE, and `preventDefault()` is for all the others.

Comment: You're wrong.  Returning false is for both, `event.preventDefault()` is for W3C model, `window.event.returnValue = false` is for IE.  Source: [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/contents.html#events)

Comment: @Eugene: Well if it doesn't work, don't you think you should be using its alternative since you're not trying to support IE. Unless you're restricted on the amount of space you have, going from 13 characters to 19 isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: First I would like to know why `return false` does not work as intended.  That's why I asked this question.

Comment: @Eugene: I have edited your answer to better demonstrate what it is that your asking.

Comment: This is OK, except that the original code does _not_ work in IE (and is not intended to work)

Answer (score 0):

I have had some cross-browser issues with the return false method.

I have had good luck just replacing the href of the like with the following:

```
function removeLink(elementName) {
   var o = document.getElementById(elementName);
   o.href = 'javascript: (function(){})();';
   o.target = "_self";
}
```

I have found that this empty function in the href property has been the easiest.

I have added the target _self part because when I develop I occasionally have these links (that I want to be hover boxes) open in a new window/tab. They need to be pointed at the current window to truly do nothing ... lol.

Hope this helps whomever.

Brynn