# Adding click event via addEventListener to confirm navigation from a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am writing some JavaScript that what I essentially want to do is confirm when a user clicks a link that they do actually want to click it.

My code currently looks like this:

```
var Anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < Anchors.length ; i++)
{
    Anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function () { return confirm('Are you sure?'); }, false);
}
```

This code displays the confirm box as I would expect to see it, but then navigates to the link regardless of the button pressed in the confirm box.

I believe the problem is related to my usage of the `addEventListener` (or a limitation of the implementation of it) because if I add manually write the following in a HTML file, the behaviour is exactly what I would expect:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Google</a><br />
```

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, and accept it. :-)

Comment: Apparently I cant post an answer to my own questions for 8 hours? If it is more use to other users as an answer I will come back and answer when I am allowed, thanks.

Comment: Well, it stops your question remaining unanswered, and (you never know) you may just get upvotes for it!

Comment: OP inactive for some years now, moved solution to an answer as community-wiki

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I changed your `onclick` function to include a call to `event.preventDefault()` and it seemed to get it working:

```
var Anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < Anchors.length ; i++) {
    Anchors[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                window.location = this.href;
            }
        }, 
        false);
}
```

(See http://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/vUP3G/1/)

Comment: Is there a speed advantage of always running preventdefault and then changing the window.location over how i have implemented it in my edit? Also, I'd never heard of jsfiddle.net before, so thanks for that as well, looks very useful.

Comment: @Andy - No, I don't think there'd be any speed advantage

Comment: just for reference to addEventListener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the execution of the default event handler.

See [How to use Javascript's addEventListener() to override an HTML Form's default submit() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731459/how-to-use-javascripts-addeventlistener-to-override-an-html-forms-default-sub)

--EDIT--

We'll, I've seen you've answered yourself while I was editing the answer

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>Solution pulled from Original Poster question</sub>*

After some more searching I have found the answer here on Stack Overflow: [Returning false from click handler doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422770/returning-false-from-click-handler-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

In case anyone finds this question instead of the other, basically when using the `addEventListener` method of wiring events, you cant just use return false; to cancel the action, you must instead use the `preventDefault()` method of the event, so my code from above has now become:

```
Anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) { 
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) { event.preventDefault(); } 
}, false);
```