# javascript redirect url with confirmation box

Tags: php, javascript

I want when user click on link he confirm if he really want to redirect in that url.Example :

```
<a href="url">name</a>
```

When he click on link confirmation box say "Do you really want to go on that page ? OK and cancel.But I have multiple numbers of  element.

Answer (score 5):

Use `onclick` event:

```
<a href="url" 
     onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to go there?');">name</a>
```

You can also use JavaScript to attach `click` handler to `a` element(s).

Comment: This work in html but in php doesn't.I must echo "<a href='#' this code>name</a>"

Comment: Why is that? Can't you alter your `echo`?

Comment: no I can't I must do it in that way :/ can you help me ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, perhaps this will help you.

Comment: It seems that this may be duplicate of [javascript adding click event via addEventListener to confirm navigation from a hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041593/javascript-adding-click-event-via-addeventlistener-to-confirm-navigation-from-a), in which you should find your answer

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
href="javascript:confirm('Leave?')?window.location='url':void(0);"
```

Comment: Hi Asad. Why do you have the void(0) in there? Is that really needed?

Comment: Hi @jmort253. The ternary operator needs a third argument.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. Thanks! Don't know how I missed that ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="url" 
    onclick="if(confirm('really?')) return true; else return false;">name</a>
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Or just return `confirm('really?')`

Comment: This will definitely get the job done, but des's solution is much more compact.

Comment: Yeah, `confirm` already returns `true` or `false` so there is no need for that `if`.