# Javascript - get a reference to dynamic anchor tag and click it through javascript

Tags: javascript, click, anchor

I am automating a web application, the data is dynamically loaded every time.
I want to click on anchor tag (selected in below image) through Javascript but the problem is there is nothing like ID, NAME which i can use to click on this link.

```
<A href="/cpy/balanceRepAccount.seb?instId=ESSESESSXXX&amp;acctNo=52018234609&amp;dateTo=2014-01-07">52018234609</A>
```

[image: code]

Working with Internet Explorer - 8

Please help me to fix this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the anchor element in the same position in the DOM every time the page is loaded?

Comment: Is the link always in the same location on on the DOM tree or does it change depending on other content?

Comment: Or is the href always the same for the anchor tag you want to click?

Comment: @PatrickQ in this case, position will be same. you can suggest some solution for this case but if you could suggest something for if position is not same that will be helpful. one more thing there will be only one anchor tag inside table.

Comment: @NuclearGhost yes its depending on other content, its not same always

Comment: @Phil no its not same alwayz

Comment: @Mike Did my answer worked for your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### jQuery style

```
$('a[href^="/cpy/balanceRepAccount.seb"]').click();
```

### Pure JS

```
function clickThatAnchor() {
    var allAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
    var numberOfAnchors = allAnchors.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfAnchors; i++) {
        if (allAnchors[i].href.indexOf('/cpy/balanceRepAccount.seb') >= 0) {
            allAnchors[i].click();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It relies on the fact the anchor you're trying to click on has a `href` containing `/cpy/balanceRepAccount.seb`.

[More information about jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), and a [working demo in pure JS](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/X3Mn8/)

Comment: '/cpy/balanceRepAccount.seb' this thing will be there, but i have to do something with javascript only.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, you could do this.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    alert("a clicked");
})
```

Comment: no, i am using javascript. please suggest something in javascipt.

Comment: He might have plenty of `a` in his page. It's going to click on all of them.

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041593/javascript-adding-click-event-via-addeventlistener-to-confirm-navigation-from-a

this code finds anchors             <script>
   var Anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < Anchors.length ; i++) {
    Anchors[i].addEventListener("click", 
        function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            alert("anchor has been clicked");
            // do stuff here
        }, 
        false);
}
            </script>