# Can't change font color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I want to click like/unlike to toggle colors of an fontawesome icon.
It works when I use a button but not work using a text link.
html part:

```
<div class='post'>
    <i class='fas fa-heart' id='h2' style='color:red'></i>
    <span>
        <a href='' class='like' bid='2' cid='h2'>like</a>
    </span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<button>click</button>
```

Works javascript:

```
var bac=document.querySelector("button");
bac.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (document.getElementById('h2').style.color=="red"){
    document.getElementById('h2').style.color="purple";
  }else if(document.getElementById('h2').style.color=="purple"){
    document.getElementById('h2').style.color="red";
  }
});
```

Not work part:(I want use this because I need to add an AJAX call)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.like').click(function(){
                var cid = $(this).attr('cid');
                if (document.getElementById('h2').style.color=="red"){
                    document.getElementById('h2').style.color="purple";
                }else if(document.getElementById('h2').style.color=="purple"){
                    document.getElementById('h2').style.color="red";
                }
            });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: Why does the vanilla JavaScript version attach the click handler to the button, but the jQuery version attach it to the anchor?

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery to do AJAX requests!

Comment: Any errors showing up in the developer tools console?

Comment: Custom attributes should be proceeded with 'data-'.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding click event via addEventListener to confirm navigation from a hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041593/adding-click-event-via-addeventlistener-to-confirm-navigation-from-a-hyperlink)

Comment: I take it there is only one element with the class 'like' on it and the id of 'h2' is unique? try putting a console.log inside your click event or a breakpoint to step through the click event handler code.

Comment: preventDefault() solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you add [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to your `click()` function.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.like').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cid = $(this).attr('cid');
        if (document.getElementById('h2').style.color == "red") {
          document.getElementById('h2').style.color = "purple";
        } else if (document.getElementById('h2').style.color == "purple") {
          document.getElementById('h2').style.color = "red";
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='post'><i class='fas fa-heart' id='h2' style='color:red'>test</i><span><a href='' class='like' bid='2' cid='h2'>like</a></span></div><br><br><button>click</button>
```

Comment: I'm going to add an AJAX call, hope both can work well.