# Return false doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hey guys i am trying to return false from my javascript method.It works fine in chrome but when same thing excutes in firefox ,its been redirected to apage with displaying false string.

Below is my code

```
    if(emptyCheck(form.corpId.value)){
        alert("Please select Corporate of the traveler");
        form.corpId.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You need to include the context (both HTML and javascript) in which this code executes and describe what you're expecting the `return false` to do.

Comment: I think we need more context here.

Comment: I'm guessing it errors out before the `return false`

Answer (score 1):

Make a parameter in the event handler called `event` or `evt`, or whatever.

Call `preventDefault()` on it:

```
document.getElementById('element').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert('this works');
    evt.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

returning `false` works only if you attach the event like this:

```
document.getElementById('element').onclick = function() {
    alert('this works');
    return false;
};
```

I have learned this on stackoverflow some time ago, I'll find you the original post.

The other thing is: If the javascript throws an exception it will fall through the return false, therefore the browser will do the default behaviour. Like clicking on a ling will navigate to that location.

Open the javascript console and check if there are any exceptions thrown!

EDIT: Here is the original post from Tim Down: [Returning false from click handler doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422770/returning-false-from-click-handler-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks guys for your guidance but i figured out the solution.I am calling a method for validation inside a if condition on the basis of true or false doing my furter execution

Answer (score 1):

you can try this;

```
if(emptyCheck(form.corpId.value)){
    alert("Please select Corporate of the traveler");
    form.corpId.focus();
    throw("exeption message");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw